# A question based on intermediate fields , separable elements , inseparable elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, separable-extension

Please consider the following question:

> Let F be an algebraic extension field of K , S the set of all elements of F
> which are separable over K, and P the set of all elements of F which are purely inseparable
> over K .Let E be an intermediate field. Then , if  $E  \cap S = K  $ then show that $E\subset P$.

using the given information I can see that $ K \subset S$ and $ K \subset E$ but I am unable to see how P will co relate to E and unable to do so which is necessary.

SO, Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is trivial in characteristic zero so we may assume that $\operatorname{char} K=p$. Take any $a\in E$. then we can write the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$ as $g(x^{p^r})$ where $g\in K[x]$ is irreducible and separable. Hence $a^{p^r}$ is a zero of $g$ and therefore separable. But by assumption $E\cap S=K$, so we get $a^{p^r}\in K$. Therefore $a$ is purely inseparable.
Note that this proof actually shows a bit more, namely that if $E\setminus K$ contains only inseparable elements, then it is already a purely inseparable extension.

Comment: Can you please tell why in case of characterstic 0 statement is trivial?

Comment: Why minimal polynomial of a over K can be written as $g(x^p^r)$ where $g\in K[x] $ where $g\in K[x] $ is irreducible and separab;e?